# Return entity key after savechanges doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have this piece of code

```
            IMG_UPLOAD_FILES tObjUploadedFile = new IMG_UPLOAD_FILES();

            tObjUploadedFile.UPLOAD_FILE_NAME = "testname.png";
            tObjUploadedFile.SETTINGS_FOLDER_ID = 2;

            dbHandler.IMG_UPLOAD_FILES.AddObject(tObjUploadedFile);
            dbHandler.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);

            decimal tmpID= tObjUploadedFile.UPLOAD_FILE_ID;
```

the tmpID is still 0 and never return a key.

I have set StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity on the required field.

I'm using the latest ODB.NET from against the ORACLE database.

\T

Comment: Open your EDMX as XML and validate that store generated pattern is correctly configured in both SSDL (table definition) and CSDL (entity definition) parts.

Comment: `        <EntityType Name="IMG_UPLOAD_FILES">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="UPLOAD_FILE_ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="UPLOAD_FILE_ID" Nullable="false" Precision="38" Scale="0" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Type="String" Name="UPLOAD_FILE_NAME" MaxLength="255" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Type="Decimal" Name="SETTINGS_FOLDER_ID" Precision="38" Scale="0" />
        </EntityType>`

Comment: That's the CSDL. Did you also check the SSDL, as @LadislavMrnka suggested?

Comment: `<EntityType Name="IMG_UPLOAD_FILES"><Key><PropertyRef Name="UPLOAD_FILE_ID" /></Key><Property Name="UPLOAD_FILE_ID" Type="number" Nullable="false" /><Property Name="UPLOAD_FILE_NAME" Type="nvarchar2" MaxLength="255" /><Property Name="SETTINGS_FOLDER_ID" Type="number" /></EntityType>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can come to finding an answer is:

Because Oracle uses a Sequence + Trigger to make "Auto Ident" values, it seems like when the entity framework adds an object at saves it, the value return is still 0, because the trigger/sequence haven't updated it yet.

So the only way to come round this is to get the object again after you have save it.

\T

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to manually (yes, manually!) go into the edmx, add the `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` attribute in the SSDL part, AND the `annonation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` in the CSDL part.

It's not broken on the SQL side, however it is definitely broken on the Oracle side of things.